# Everything shrinks to size but my image on browser and mobile? Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build my friends website with bootstrap and when I decrease the size of the page everything (including a video and all the text) shrinks, but for some reason the logo I am using will not shrink and goes behind the video when the browser window shrinks, on mobile, it puts the whole webpage out of balance because it is displaying at full size instead of shrinking alongside the rest of the page?

This is a small screenshot of how it looks as it should on a desktop with the browser window full screen - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lrxZ.png)
This is what it does when I shrink the browser window, as you can see the text and video box shrinks beautifully, logo...not so much;
[Image Screencap here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL2L3.png)

```
<section id="hero" data-type="background" data-speed="5">
        <article>
            <div class="container clearfix">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <img src="assets/img/logo-badge.png" alt="Bootstrap to Wordpress" class="logo">
                    </div><!-- col -->

                            <div class="col-sm-6 hero-text">

                        <video width="100%" height="410" controls>
  <source src="assets/img/Flanamation.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>




        </article>  

    </section><!--hero-->
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: there, on your image, you have `col-sm-6` it won't shrink unless your device < 768px. [read more on bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options), try to change it to `col-md-6` -- but well, it'll only make it stacked. to make it smaller, use `img-responsive` ([reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030009/make-logo-image-responsive-using-bootstrap))

Comment: Stacking works too! I guess just my image size is too wide? Thought because just before it stacks, it hides slightly behind the video. Maybe I'll experiment with that. I havent heard of the img-responsive, where do I add that into the code? Thanks for the help!

Comment: you could add `img-responsive` on your `<img>` class, just after `logo`. oh well, tbh, when i read your question i can't decide whether i should suggest stacking or just make it's size shrink..

Answer (score 0):

Using .img-responsive typically works in bootstrap, but as the other comment mentioned really I would not wrap the image in the current container. Typically myself I center the logo at the top using bootstrap. Something like this works:

```html
<section id="hero" data-type="background" data-speed="5">
  <article>
    <div class="container clearfix">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <img src="assets/img/logo-badge.png" alt="Bootstrap to Wordpress" class="logo">
        </div>
        <!-- col -->
        <div class="col-sm-6 hero-text">
          <video width="100%" height="410" controls>
            <source src="assets/img/Flanamation.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Also, it's worth noting that you had a few containers that were not closed off. Remember when writing HTML that every element must be closed in order for it to work properly.

Tough to say exactly the right solution as we don't really know the look your going for, but I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Give logo class img-responsive

```
<img some code 
class="img-responsive">
```

Its a bootstrap class

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use media query. for example

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
.logo{
    height: 70px;
}
}
```

Use this in your css file